# How do I change the Applications folder icon

Tags: finder, dock, monterey, icon

I know how to change the folder icon for any other folder by pasting the image into the info box of the folder, however this does not seem to work with the "Applications" folder.

No matter what I try I still end up with the default blue folder with the "A"

I would like to use a different icon because I keep Applications in the dock and I just want something different.

*MacOS Monterey 12.5*

Comment: you can e.g. create an alias and change it icons. but more importantly: which version of MacOS?

Comment: I tagged the question as monterey but I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you can't change it. The "Macintosh HD" volume is actually made up of two separate volumes:

- one is read-only, containing the OS and Apple-bundled applications;
- the other is "Macintosh HD - Data", and contains your applications,
  your /Library files, plus user accounts, and everything else.

The OS then presents both volumes 'merged' together in the Finder (and in the Terminal). The Applications folder technically exists on both volumes, but presumably the read-only one takes precedence.

You could try creating an alias to the Applications folder, customizing that, and then putting that in the Dock...?

MacOS has always had limited scope for customization of appearance.

Answer (score 0):

After opening your homefolder (to see Applications), right click and select "get info".
Drag a new image on top of the existing one and close the "Application Info" window.
Restart finder and/or the machine (whichever you're feeling more comfortable with) and that should update the icon.

Comment: Same as pasting.  I suspect SIP will prevent it.